# Android App is crashing Intel XDK

Tags: android, ionic-framework, intel-xdk

I am creating an app Img2Pdf. Whenever I am trying to debug or run (debug tab in intel XDK), this app Genymotion emulator, app this crashing.

[image]

Even this app has nothing, just a blank app.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use Genymotion as a target device for the Debug tab, is that correct? I recommend you use a real device. We do not test against that tool and cannot guarantee that it will work properly. Another option is to build the app and debug against the built image, see these instructions > https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/intel-xdk-debug-and-test-overview#RemoteChromeDevTools < for details on how to do that.

Comment: old version of intel XDK were working fine. this issue is there for last 3 intel XDK releases. Also when I am using ionic CLI, it is working.